# Samsung galaxy note knocking off other computers wifii

Tags: wi-fi

My Samsung galaxy note 10.1 32gb knocks off the other computers on the WiFi network when I connect.  Mine connects fine, but the other computers (laptops) get knocked off and have to be rebooted or repaired to gain access again.  Why does this happen and how can I fix it?

Comment: You'll have to explain what you mean by "repaired", as this usually implies some sort of physical damage or corruption.  Have you made any changes to your router to assign IP addresses to devices that connect to it based on their MAC address?  Perhaps you've assigned multiple MAC addresses the same IP address?

Answer (score 1):

Your Phone might be connecting to the Wi-FI network  using a static IP (thus knocking off whatever device is also using that same IP to connect), go to advanced settings on your connection and choose DHCP, that should fix it.